# Banach space $n \times n$ Matrices - check my proof

Tags: matrices, limits, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

Show that the vector space $M_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$ which contains $n \times n$ Matrices is a Banach space.

Let be $\Vert \cdot\Vert_{max}= max_{1\leq i,j \leq n}\vert a_{ij}\vert$ the maximum of the absolute value of all entries of a matrix $A$.

My proof:

We show that every Cauchy sequence has a limit in $M_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$. I will construct such a limit matrix $C$ as follows:

Let $(A_m)_{m \to \infty}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $M_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$. So there exists a $m_0$ such that for every $m>m_0$ it holds: $\Vert A_m - A_{m_0}\Vert_{max} < \epsilon$, where $0<\epsilon$.

We define a sequence $(f_{m,i,j})_{m \to \infty}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:

$f_{m,i,j}= a_{ij}$, where $a_{ji}$ is the ij-th entry of Matrix $A_m$ which is the $m$-th member of the sequence $(A_m)_{m \to \infty}$.

Let be $f_{m_0,i,j}= b_{ji}$, where $b_{ji}$ is the $ij$-th entry of Matrix $A_{m_0}$. We then have for $f_m$ which consists of an arbitrary entry $a_{ij}$ of $A_m$: $\vert f_{m,i,j} - f_{m_0,i,j}\vert \leq max_{1\leq i, j \leq n}\vert a_{ij} - b_{ij} \vert = \Vert A_m - A_{m_0}\Vert_{max} < \epsilon $. So every sequence $f_m$ which is constructed from entries of $A_m$ is a Cauchy sequence and as we know that $\mathbb{R}$ is complete it is also convergent. Let $c$ be the limit of a sequence $f_{m,i,j}$. Let $C$ be a matrix in $M_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$which consists of all those $c$'s.

By definition of convergence there exists an index $m_0$ such that for a sequence $f_{m,i,j}$ which is constructed from a arbitrary $a_{ij}$ entry of $A_m$ we have: $\forall m > m_0: \vert f_{m,i,j} - c_{ij}\vert< \epsilon$. We then choose the greatest index $m_0$ out of all sequences $f_m$. We then consider our inital sequence $(A_m)_{m \to \infty}$. If we set our index: $m>m_0$ it yields $\Vert A_m - C \Vert_{max}= max_{1\leq i,j \leq n}\vert f_{m,i,j} - c_{ij}\vert< \epsilon$. So our sequence $(A_m)_{m \to \infty}$ is convergent which shows that every Cauchy sequence in $M_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$ is convergent and hence $M_{nn}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Banach space. q.e.d.

Although it is not very elegant and somewhat brute force I want to now if this serves as a rigorous proof or are there any flaws?

Any comments are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Globally, it is correct, but it could be improved:

- You should have stated at the statement that you wished to prove which norm you were using, instead of introducing it in the middle of the proof.
- At the second paragraph of your proof, you mention $\varepsilon$, without saying what it is.
- Each $f_m$ also depends upon $i$ and $j$; therefore, $f_{m,i,j}$ would be a better choice of notation.

Comment: so you want to put the definition of the maximum norm at the beginning of the proof? Or do you mean that it shouldn't be part of the proof but mentioned beforehand?

Comment: It shoud be mentioned beforehand.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that because our tutor always comes up with defining norms when she uses them.